# From Android Studio to intelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I've installed Android Studio and now I need IntelliJ IDEA, can I convert/extend Android Studio to IntelliJ IDEA community edition?
Is the installation of IntelliJ IDEA community edition the only way to having both?

Comment: IntelliJ is the best IDE on the market.  I don't see why you need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'd strongly recommend getting Ultimate Edition, you [should be able to use Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) to develop on Android.

Provided that you have the Android plugin installed, it should be a matter of importing your existing project into IntelliJ.

You can't convert one into another since they're different programs/platforms, but IntelliJ can generally run what the other IDEs out there can with plugin support.